# Alias domain to Multi-site installation in Apache

Tags: multisite, domain, configuration, apache, dns

This is regarding to set an Alias domain to Multi-site installation.

We want to create a short domain as alias to my main website(Multi-Site enabled).I have tried it using a most common options like...

1)Creating cname records,

2)pointing to main installation location as  addon domain

3)Domain parking

When we try the first two options it is redirecting to sign up page of Web-Site(I think Wild card redirect for Multi-site installation is the reason).

The third option is making is showing an error :"Debugging a Wordpress Network"

I think that I should configure it in Apache to solve the problem(I have root access).But I am not aware of dealing with  Apache

When we contact our host,they are not trying to look in to the issue and simply said that  they would re-install the whole web-site again. I don't want to do that.

Could anybody help me with this

**Update**: I needed this domain Alias for a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/le-petite-url/) which enable us to shorten the URL with out any third party service . I have  Doncha's **Domain mapping plugin** installed and I don't know how to use it in this situation

Thanks!

**Update 2 :** : I mean to say that the domain mapping plugin doesn't work with main site.It is only useful to map the sub-domains under a multi-site installation. I read some where over internet that the main site cannot be aliased with this plugin as it causes some problems . Could any body help to alias the main site in an alternative way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the domain mapping plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/
http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Comment: Andrea ! I have installed Domain mapping plugin already. But I don't know how it is useful to work with  ' Le Petite URL ' plugin